# select campo texto separado por virgula retornar linhas

Tags: postgresql

Alguém sabe como é possível no `postgresql` pegar um valor dentro de um campo do tipo `TEXT` que tem registros separados por virgula para usar no `WHERE`?

Exemplo dos valores no campo (35693,35694,35695,35696,35697,35698,35699,713)

Exemplo

```
Select * from tabela where id = '35693'
```

Porem o valor no `where` esta dentro de uma string separada por virgula, como quebrar e comparar?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `array_position` combinada com a função `regexp_split_to_array`.

```
array_position(regexp_split_to_array(seu_campo_texto), elemento_a_pesquisar) NOT NULL
```

Caso a função array_position retorne NULL é porque o elemento não existe no texto.

Outra possibilidade, mais simples, é utilizar a função `position`:

```
position(elemento in seu_campo_texto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando :

```
UNNEST(ARRAY[string_to_array(campo_pesquizar, ',')])::INT
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE id IN (35693,35694,35695,35696,35697,35698,35699,713);
```

Desculpem esta sugestão retorna valores para todos os campos da lista.